# Postgres, Count entries on daily basis

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query to find out the number of packages impacted on daily basis.

- Only include packages from the 6th onwards
- Only packages with status = 'sent'
- Daily basis

This is the query I currently have:

```
SELECT 
date_ts, count(current_status) AS no_of_package
FROM freight_daily
WHERE   
TO_CHAR(date_ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd')>= '2021-01-04'
AND     current_status = 'sent'
GROUP BY date_ts;
```

MY result:

| Date_ts | No_of_package |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 08:45:33 | 400 |
| 2021-01-04 09:55:27 | 800 |
| 2021-01-04 15:16:14 | 250 |
| 2021-01-04 23:29:43 | 400 |

Desired result

| Date_ts | No_of_package |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-06 | 8000 |
| 2021-01-07 | 9000 |
| 2021-01-08 | 5000 |
| 2021-01-09 | 6500 |

Comment: Do not filter date columns with strings, it disables index usage or partition pruning. Use `date_ts >= date '2021-01-04'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just truncate your date as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day',date_ts), 
       count(current_status) AS no_of_package
  FROM freight_daily
 WHERE --TO_CHAR(date_ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd')>= '2021-01-04'
       date_ts >= TIMESTAMP '2021-01-04 00:00:00'
   AND current_status = 'sent'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day',date_ts);
```